# How do I resolve this exception?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-workbench

**Good morning SO,**

I'm having a bit of trouble with this query.  It works fine when I tested it in the Workbench, but VB is throwing an exception that the column "ccID" is unknown.  Am I doing something wrong?  My intent is to pull the ccID field and the difference between today and the date in field ccAuthorizedUseEnd.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**HERE'S THE QUERY I TESTED IN THE MySQL WORKBENCH:**

```
SELECT ccID, DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), ccAuthorizedUseEnd) AS Days
FROM accounting.cc_master
```

**HERE'S THE SAME QUERY I'M USING IN VB.NET**

```
Dim dbQuery2 As String = "SELECT ccID, DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), ccAuthorizedUseEnd) as Days "
```

Comment: where's the rest of the VB query? (or should we assume it's the same thing as the workbench being supplied?)

Comment: Brad, do you mean the rest of the query including the connection string, etc?

Comment: No, I just assume `sbQuery2` doesn't stop at `...as Days"`

Comment: Well duh!  How could I forgot the FROM statment.  So silly of me, thanks....cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten your FROM clause in the VB.NET version:

```
Dim dbQuery2 As String = "SELECT ccID, DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), ccAuthorizedUseEnd) as Days FROM accounting.cc_master"
```